# Calculating yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores for a yarn cluster with multiple spark clients

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

If I have 3 spark applications all using the same yarn cluster, how should I set

`yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`

in each of the 3 yarn-site.xml?

(each spark application is required to have it's own yarn-site.xml on the classpath)

**Does this value even matter in the client yarn-site.xml's ?**

If it does:

Let's say the cluster has 16 cores.

Should the value in each yarn-site.xml be 5 (for a total of 15 to leave 1 core for system processes) ? Or should I set each one to 15 ?

(Note: Cloudera indicates one core should be left for system processes here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/ however, they do not go into details of using multiple clients against the same cluster)

Assume Spark is running with yarn as the master, and running in cluster mode.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the server-side configuration for each YARN Node Manager? If so, it would typically be configured to be a little less than the number of CPU cores (or virtual cores if you have hyperthreading) on each node in the cluster. So if you have 4 nodes with 4 cores each, you could dedicate for example 3 per node to the YARN node manager and your cluster would have a total of 12 virtual CPUs.

Then you request the desired resources when submitting the Spark job (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html for example) to the cluster and YARN will attempt to fulfill that request. If it can't be fulfilled, your Spark job (or application) will be queued up or there will eventually be a timeout.

You can configure different resource pools in YARN to guarantee a specific amount of memory/CPU resources to such a pool, but that's a little bit more advanced.

If you submit your Spark application in cluster mode, you have to consider that the Spark driver will run on a cluster node and not your local machine (that one that submitted it). Therefore it will require at least 1 virtual CPU more.

Hope that clarifies things a little for you.

Comment: Spark has a client side configuration using yarn-site.xml. I have multiple spark jobs being submitted from different apps, each with it's own client side yarn-site.xml.

Comment: Well, in that case if you request all resources of the cluster with one application, the next one has to wait in a queue for the first to finish.

Comment: My only worry is that this value is ignored on the client, and the server side yarn-site.xml value for yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores is the only one that matters. I wont have a cluster to test with again for some time to confirm one way or another and the blog post isn't clear.

Comment: How do you start the Spark job from your application? If you're using the `spark-submit` script you should use the `--executor-cores` and the `--num-executors` options. Using the `SparkSubmit` or `SparkLauncher` classes directly has something equivalent.

The `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` property is only used on the server side as far as I know. Node manager is the component that runs on each worker node that is part of a YARN cluster.

Comment: The job is submitted via java using a SparkConf object. Spark requires a yarn-site.xml on the classpath, but it's unclear what it actually reads out of it.

Comment: Okay, in that case you can set the appropriate properties on the `SparkConf` object via the `set` or `setIfMissing` methods. The property names are detailed in a table at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html -- e.g. `spark.executor.cores` or `spark.executor.instances` instead of `--executor-cores` and `--num-executors` on the command line. When you use `setIfMissing` you can theoretically override the settings from the outside (if you should choose to use the `spark-submit` script at some point for example)

Comment: I am setting those the way that you mention (and have tweaked them a great deal), but just discovered yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores in yarn-site.xml and wondered if it mattered inside my java app. Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: No problem! Another crazy idea since you mentioned Cloudera/CDH in your original post: Can you log into the Cloudera Manager user interface, go to the YARN section and then download the client configuration file (there should be a link to do that in the Actions dropdown menu IIRC). Does that file also contain this setting?